# Is there a convenient way to import a exist c files(with lots of files & folder hierarchy) to become a Visual Studio project?(VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Eclipse there is a "import" option that let a Java source codes become a Eclipse project; Howerver, in Visual Studio, there seems no such option that can import a exist c files(with lots of files & folder hierarchy & make files) to become a Visual Studio project! Or is there a such option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got to "File", "New", "Project from Existing Code...", and select the appropriate root directory. The "Add Subfolders" checkbox *should* normally be checked by default, but you can un-check it if you have some directories that have sub-directories you *don't* want added.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I can import all files now! But after the "import" operation, the original hierarchy disappeared!(all files are put under Source files/Header files regardless the subdirectories in original source codes) Is there a way to keep original hierarchy?

Comment: @maple: You can re-create the original hierarchy if you want to badly enough, but at least as far as I know, you have to do it manually (I've done it a couple of times, but it's rarely worth it).